# Decision Making Statements in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a condition where displayed records depend on value provided by the user.

```
select calc_lvl1,   calc_lvl2,  calc_lvl3
from my_table
where comment=:user_value;
```

Possible values in comment column are `'NEW'`,`'ACCEPTED'`, and `'REJECTED'`. And there can be new values in this column in the future as well, and this query should be working in the future as well irrespective of number of distinct values present in comment column.

My requirement is that if user doesn't supply any value, then all `'NEW'` records should be displayed, and if user enters value `'Y'` then everything else except `'NEW'` should be displayed.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select calc_lvl1, calc_lvl2, calc_lvl3
from my_table
where comment = user_value
  or (user_value is null and comment = 'NEW')
  or (user_value = 'Y' and comment <> 'NEW')
```